# Databricks notebook integrated mlflow artifact location and retention

Tags: azure-databricks, mlflow

1. Currently by default in notebook run, it will create an experiment ID, but the Artifact Location would point to something under dbfs:/databricks/mlflow/{experiment id}. If there is a way we may change this in default experiment creation? We like to manage the storage outside databricks.
2. How long is default TTL for experiment runs and metrics? Is it configurable and how?

Comment: What is TTL?  Need more info to answer your question!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mlflow_set_experiment('<PATH>')` to specify where you want your runs and all of their contents to be logged.  See the docs [here.](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.set_experiment)

If you are working on Databricks and want to log to a particular blob storage, you can [mount the blob storage](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage) to Databricks File System (DBFS) and point MLflow to it when you set the experiment.

If you are talking about running it in Databricks and directly logging the results locally, I don't think you can do that.  However, you can use GitHub and [MLflow Projects](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html) to develop on Databricks and then run locally, or vice versa.